# Копирование файлов из одной папки в другую через web приложение

Tags: java, html, веб-программирование, jsp

Приложение должно копировать все файлы из одной директории в другую, и ввод пути директории откуда и куда должно осуществляться через Web приложение. 
Имеется два файла.JSP:

1.Главная страница где два поля для ввода (from, to).

2.И вторая, где вернется значение, что все файлы скопированы.

Вот что смог накатать, дальше полный ступор, что делать дальше...

СopyFiles.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.omg.Security.Public;


public class CopyFiles {



       private String text1;
       private String text2;

       public void setText1(String text1) {
               this.text1 = text1;
       }
       public void setText2(String text2) {
               this.text2 = text2;
       }           

       public String getText1() {
                      return text1;
    }

    public String getText2() {
                      return text2;
       }




    public List<String> getList() {
         return getFiles(new src(text1), new dest(text2));
    }

       public void copy (File src, File dest) throws IOException {

             if (src.isDirectory())
               {
                    if(!dest.exists())
                    {
                           dest.mkdir();
                           System.out.println("Папка скопирована из " + src + " в " + dest);
                    }

                    String files[] = src.list();

                    for (String fileName : files)
                    {
                           File srcFile = new File (src, fileName);
                           File destFile = new File (dest, fileName);
                           copy(srcFile, destFile);
                    }
               }
             else
             {
                    fileCopy(src, dest);
             }
       }

       private void fileCopy(File src, File dest) throws IOException
       {
             InputStream in = null;
             OutputStream out = null;

             try
             {
                    in = new FileInputStream(src);
                    out = new FileOutputStream(dest);

                    byte[] buffer = new byte [1024];

                    int lenght;

                    while ((lenght = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
                    {
                           out.write(buffer, 0, lenght);
                    }
             }
             finally
             {
                    if (in != null)
                    {
                           in.close();
                    }
                    if (out != null)
                    {
                           out.close();
                    }
             }
             System.out.println("Файлы скопированы из: " + src + " в " + dest);
       }

}
```

index.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@page language="java"
       contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>mainpage</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<br>

    <td>
       <form action="copypage.jsp" method="POST" >
                           Сopy From :  <input type="text" name="text1" >  to  <input type="text" name="text2" >
                           <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>

       </form>
    </td>

</body>
</html>
```

copypage.jsp

```
!DOCTYPE HTML><%@page language="java"contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@page import="ru.sbrf.asfs.stub.getCardInfo.CopyFiles"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>

<%      CopyFiles copyfiles = new CopyFiles();

String from = request.getParameter("text1");
String to = request.getParameter("text2");

System.out.print(from);
System.out.print(to);

copyfiles.setText1(from);
copyfiles.setText1(to);

  %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Copypage</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно Вам необходимо сделать web-приложение и запустить его на одном из http серверов. [Например](http://www.journaldev.com/1877/servlet-tutorial-java), можете сделать сервлет и запустить его на контейнере сервлетов tomcat, а с jsp страницы его вызывать.